# Can a motherboard's USB controller / port be damaged if an externally powered USB cable is plugged into a powered USB port?

Tags: usb, laptop, motherboard, power-supply, capacitor

I mistakenly plugged a USB cable into a powered USB-C port on my laptops motherboard that was concurrently plugged into a 5V 2A USB to Wall AC adapter. Nothing seemed to happen at the time but could doing something like that cause a hardware issue that is not immediately apparent? My immediate concern was a possible issue with capacitors or the laptop trying to draw current to the batteries through the USB-C connector.

Comment: Did you plug an externally powered, USB Type-C hub, into a port on your machine? That is completely normal.

Comment: No. Basically plugged an AC adapter directly into a powered motherboard USB port.

Comment: If it ain't broke, don't fix it. *Could* there be hidden damage? Unlikely, but as long as it works, use it.

Comment: Was it a USB-PD charger? Does the charger have a type-C port or a type-A port?

Comment: Im unsure if it is a USB-PD charger but the charger has a type-A port